# AWS console not showing all instances during volume attach

Tags: amazon-ec2

I do the following using AWS web console:

1. Attach EBS volume-A to instance-A. Make some changes to data on volume-A and detach it
2. Launch new instance-B (in the same zone as instance-A)
3. Try attach volume-A to the new instance-B. But the new instance does not appear in the instances list during attach volume process (dialog box).

If I try the same attach using command line EC2 API (volume-A and instance-B), it works fine!

Do you know if this is a bug in AWS web console or am I doing something wrong in the console? Tried page refresh in Step #3 but it still would not list the new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I had faced this problem yesterday and a day before. It looks like Amazon problem with their cache. Not sure WHY.

To bring back the stuff as is, I had to sign-out and make sure things are good. But it's always good to work with CLI, works better.

Comment: Looks like it is a known problem then. Thanks for confirming. Yes, I agree on the CLI option. Very easy to use and faster as well since the typical delays involved in web page refresh are completely avoided.

Comment: why is this the accepted answer not really helpful, Igor's answer should be the accepted one

Answer (score 9):

In order to attach, both volumes has to be in the same zone. So if you are going to attach a volume into a instance check the zone of the instance's attached volume. If those are not matching create a new instance with the same zone as the zone of the volume that you need to attached.

Comment: I overlooked this - and it's actually very pertinent to the issue... a +1 from me.

Answer (score 5):

The volume and the instance have to be in the same region **AND the same zone**.

If you have a **volume** in `us-east-1a` and the **instance** in `us-east-1b`, you would need to move the volume to `us-east-1b` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Although the user interface may not list the instance ID, you can attempt to add the volume anyway. If it's genuinely impossible (rather than a cache issue) you will get an error message.

Paste in the instance ID (i-xxxxxxx) manually then type your mount point (e.g. /dev/sdf) and click Attach.

For the benefit of others: some instance types do not support encrypted volumes, which may be why the instance doesn't appear in the list. I get the following error:

```
Error attaching volume: 'vol-12341234' is encrypted and 't2.medium' does not support encrypted volumes.
```